# Generic types, collections and object reference

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic type `GenericClass<Type_T>` (`Type_T` implements `IType_T` if it helps). I create some instances of it, for example `GenericClass<Type1>`, `GenericClass<Type2>`.

No I want an index over a bunch of theses class instances.
I first thought about a dictionary : `Dictionary<int, GenericClass<Type1>>` which obviously doesn't work.

Is there a known solution to this problem ? How to store an indexed collection of generic types ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also look at [covariance in generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You also need to define a common interface for GenericClass but it can be generic:

```
interface IType { }
interface IGenericClass<out T> where T : IType { }
class Type1 : IType { }
class Type2 : IType { }
class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass<T> where T : IType { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Dictionary<int, IGenericClass<IType>> dict = new Dictionary<int, IGenericClass<IType>>();
                dict[0] = new GenericClass<Type2>();
                dict[1] = new GenericClass<Type1>();
     }
}
```

But it won't allow:

```
 Dictionary<int, IGenericClass<object>> dict = new Dictionary<int, IGenericClass<object>>();
```

Edit: For completeness

You can't use this to pass IType as parameter in IGenericClass. It requires contravariance and using contravariance will break the assignment to `Dictionary<int, IGenericClass<IType>> dict`:

> A covariant type parameter is marked with the out keyword (Out keyword
>   in Visual Basic, + for the MSIL Assembler). You can use a covariant
>   type parameter as the return value of a method that belongs to an
>   interface, or as the return type of a delegate. You cannot use a
>   covariant type parameter as a generic type constraint for interface
>   methods.

```
 interface IGenericClass<out T> where T : IType
 {
    T GetType(); //possible
    void SetType(T t); //not possible
 }
```

Comment: Is `IGenericClass<out T> where T : IType { }` necessary ?
Can't it be directly `class GenericClass<out T> : where T : IType { }` ?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. The out/in keywords only work with interfaces (or delegates).

Comment: Ho, my bad, i didn't even check that.. This is definitely what i was looking for ! Thank you.

Comment: @Nicolas Voron I just added more information to this Post. You can't  have methods where IType is a parameter. So depending on your use case it may not work.

Answer (score 6):

Normally what you do in this case is create a common non-generic base class (sometimes an abstract class, or a non-generic interface), `GenericClass`, from which `GenericClass<Type_T>` derives, and that contains the methods that don't have as a parameter/return type the `Type_T`. You use this base class/interface exactly for what you wrote: `Dictionary<int, GenericClass>`...

A race-to-the-bottom is: `Dictionary<int, object>`, because `object` is the base class for all the class types in .NET.

Classical case: `List<T>` derives from `IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`.

Comment: That was not mentioned, but my `GenericClass<Type_T>` includes a `Type_T my_variable` field, and the generic interface will not feet my needs in this case since i want to be able to invoke this field without tricky casts. But this is a good answer for someone else who have not this constraint. Generic covariance feets more my specific needs.

Answer (score 3):

A compact code example following up on xanatos' answer:

```
interface IType { }
interface IGenericClass { }
class Type1 : IType { }
class Type2 : IType { }
class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass where T : IType { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gen1 = new GenericClass<Type1>();
        var gen2 = new GenericClass<Type2>();
        var list = new List<IGenericClass>();
        list.Add(gen1);
        list.Add(gen2);
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, my friend. @NicolasVoron

Answer (score 1):

Almost similar with an answer by Hjalmar Z but the change is instead of List I have used ObservableCollection. Which probably would serve the problem of indexed collection

```
interface IType { }
interface IGenericClass { }
class Type1 : IType { }
class Type2 : IType { }
class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass where T : IType { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gen1 = new GenericClass<Type1>();
        var gen2 = new GenericClass<Type2>();
        ObservableCollection<IGenericClass> GCClass = new ObservableCollection<IGenericClass>();
        GCClass.Add(gen1);
        GCClass.Add(gen2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, but a comment on @Hjalmar Z would have been more efficient for future readers.

Comment: The idea doesnt clicked at the right moment ... BTW thanks next time I'll take care of it